# long long integer is not working in C(UNIX+AIX6.1)

Tags: c, unix, aix, long-long

## I am using cc compiler on AIX 6.1 (Unix)

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    long long var;
    scanf("%lld",&var);
    printf("%lld",var);
    return 0;
}

/* When I enter 16 digit number for above code its working*/
```

========================================

But I am not sure why below  code is not showing correct value

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    long long var=1234567890123456;
    printf("%lld",var);
    return 0;
}
```

Please Help?

Comment: After fixing the missing semicolon, it seems to work fine: http://ideone.com/2Ge1w0

Comment: Sorry! my mistake..I forgot to include ";" in above code.

Comment: Actually I am getting some garbage value in second code

Comment: @sku can you objdump the 2nd code for us?

Comment: Does this work? `long long var=1234567890123456LL;` (And what value is being printed?)

Comment: Thank you rici...long long var=1234567890123456LL; is working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @rici points out, the problem is with the `var` assignment.

```
// long long var=1234567890123456;
long long var=1234567890123456LL;  // append LL
printf("%lld",var);
```

`1234567890123456` was too large for `int` and `unsigned` in *OP* environment.  To specify higher values, use the desire suffix.

---

I suspect `1015724736` was printed out by the OP originally as 1234567890123456 % 4294967296.  4294967296 being the assumed range of of OP's `unsigned` ( 0 to  4294967295).

Answer (score 0):

Usually `%lld` works for cc. Try `%I64d`

Comment: Scotty, Could you please tell me what is objdump and how to objdump a C code?

Comment: @sku, What objdump does is disassembles the compiled C file from binary to assembly instruction. I asked you to obj dump it because sometimes the compiler makes assumptions about your code that you didn't mean. You can read more about objdump here: http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2012/09/objdump-examples/